# String Binary Search Keeps Returning Error

Tags: java, binary-search

I have been trying to make a binary search that searches through a list of sorted words. I am having a bit of trouble as it can find some words but other words return -1.

Here is the code to my binary search :

```
public static int binarySearch(List <String> sortedAL, String key, int lowIndex, int highIndex)
{
    int middle = (lowIndex + highIndex) / 2;

    if(highIndex < lowIndex)
    {
        //System.out.println(-1);
        return -1;
    }

    if(key.equalsIgnoreCase(sortedAL.get(middle)))
    {
        return middle;
    }

    /*
        str1.compareTo(str2)

        * if s1 > s2, it returns positive number  
        * if s1 < s2, it returns negative number  
        * if s1 == s2, it returns 0  
     */

    else if(key.compareToIgnoreCase(sortedAL.get(middle)) < 0)
    {
        return binarySearch(sortedAL, key, lowIndex, middle - 1);
    }

    else
    {
        return binarySearch(sortedAL, key, middle + 1, highIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Run your code step-by-step under debugger for cases when it does not work properly.  You will be able to examine every intermediate value and compare it with your expectation.

Comment: It would also help to post a [mcve].  Add a few words to the list and then show us a search that incorrectly returns -1.  There might be other issues besides the search algorithm above.

Comment: I would check the sorting algorithm and debug it as @PM77-1 said

Comment: Use `Collections.sort(AL)`  to get `sortedAL` and then check if the problem still persists. If problem is gone its most likely your sorting algo.

Comment: Are you confident that in the cases you get -1, the word you are searching for is in fact in the list?

Comment: Previously, when it looked through a dictionary for the words "horse" or "zoo", it would return -1. Turns out sorting was the problem, when I got the dictionary, it already looked sorted and didn't bother sorting it, I added Collections.Sort and it started to work. Thank you to all the people who pointed out my sorting may be at fault